# S3 CORS upload aborts after passing OPTIONS

Tags: upload, amazon-s3, cors, put

I'm trying to upload a file from my browser and it don't work at all.

My bucket CORS configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And in my code I'm sending this:

```
xhr.open('PUT', "http://upload.test.s3.amazonaws.com/" + uploadFile.get("dest") +'?' +   "partNumber=" + (part + 1) +  "&" + "uploadId=" + uploadFile.get("uploadId"), true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", uploadFile.get("authorization"));
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", uploadFile.get("date"));
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", uploadFile.get("rawFile").type);
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
xhr.send(chunk);
```

Ps: The uploadFile has some properties like the authorization key and uploadId that comes from the server.

When the upload starts I pass trough the OPTIONS request but the Put request gets aborted after a few seconds ( usually 4-5 seconds after sending some content percentage ). Unfortunately it gets aborted with no feedback.
Does anyone knows what could be happening??

Thanks!

Edit: Basically I'm using https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox to get the UploadId from the Multipart Upload ( it works if I use the server for the whole upload operation )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server can't use wildcards (i.e. "*") if you use CORS Authorization: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499465/cors-and-http-basic-auth) out.

Have you tried specifying the requesting domain in the AllowedOrigin header of your bucket?