# CORS authentication with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, cors

I've read a lot of documentation about CORS and authentication, and I'm pretty sure to do things correctly. I'm trying to authenticate a jQuery.ajax GET CORS request, like this:

```
$.ajax('http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar', {
    type: 'GET',
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'bar',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
}).then(function (data) {
    alert('success');
}, function (xhr) {
    alert('failure');
});
```

but the browser keeps prompting me for credentials, not sending the provided ones. Try this at http://jsfiddle.net/BpYc3/ where http://httpbin.org is supposed to send correct CORS headers.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar. Credentials flag is true, but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not "true".` are you sure the server is allowing cross-origin credentials? I haven't had to deal with this, but that's where i would look first due to that error.

Comment: @KevinB Right, httpbin.org doesn't set that header for GET requests, but even if I set that header on my API server, the browser still prompts for credentials.

Answer (score 5):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499465/cors-and-http-basic-auth) out.

If your server asks for credentials, then you can't use

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

with the wildcard: you must specify the allowed domain.