# Basic HTTP authorization header

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http-headers, http-authentication

I would like to set-up a basic HTTP-Authentication using JQuery on the client-side and Node.js on the server side. 
I have made the following Ajax request on the server side to set the headers:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URL_SLACK_SERVER,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +btoa("username:xxx") );
        },
        success:function(rsp){
            filterMessages(rsp);
        }
    });
```

Which I want to use on my server side using the [basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth) module:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var auth = require('basic-auth');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Key");
  var cre = +auth(req);
  console.log('Auth: ' +cre.username);
  next();
});
```

But, doing this way, I encounter some issues:

1. I do not see that the header are set in the preflight OPTIONS HTTP request:

> OPTIONS /server HTTP/1.1 
>       Host: server.com 
>       Connection: keep-alive 
>       Access-Control-Request-Method: GET 
>       Origin: null
>       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111
>   Safari/537.36
>       Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
>       Accept: */*
>       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>       Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6

2. I got the following error, which I do not understand well:

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Also, please note that the call from the client to the server is a cross-domain call, that's why there is these set headers written on the Node.js file.

How can I efficiently perform this basic HTTP-Authentication?

Comment: Looks like your server and client are running on different domain and the server doesn't have proper CORS headers set.

Comment: They indeed run on different domain (see the end of my question). Which headers can I add on  the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your client and server are running on different domains, you need to configure the CORS header in your server to make it work.

You need to set the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://foo.example"` or `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"` in your server.

Comment: Is it not enough to just write `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` ?

Comment: That will also work but will make it accessible to any domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a cors problem.
When you enable cors in npm (Look for cors module and append it via npm) you can set a specific domain that is allowed. When you set this the basic authentication header will be send with the request.
Look at this request:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511690/3232739